# Java Oracle PreparedStatement ARRAY parameter passing empty strings

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, prepared-statement

The following call to a pipelined function works perfectly when called from an SQL worksheet. It also works perfectly when passed in from Java as a complete literal string.

```
select * from table(PKG.GetStuff(
    param_array => str_arr_t(
        'field1 LIKE ''foo%''', 
        'field2 LIKE ''bar%''')
));
```

But if I try to parameterize the call in Java with setArray() I get empty strings in the oracle function.  The array count is correct but the values are empty.

STR_ARR_T is define on the schema as:

```
create or replace TYPE STR_ARR_T AS TABLE OF varchar2(50);
```

The Java call is:

```
PreparedStatement statement = 
    connection.prepareCall("select * from table(PKG.GetStuff(param_array => ?))");
ArrayDescriptor ad1 = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("STR_ARR_T", connection);
ARRAY arr = new ARRAY(ad1, connection, myStringArray);
statement.setArray(1, arr);
```

The plsql inside the function handles the array as follows.  It loops correctly but concatenates empty strings into the dynamic sql.

```
FOR J IN 1 .. param_array.COUNT
LOOP
  sql := sql || ' AND ' || param_array(J);
END LOOP;
```

I don't get any errors until I try to execute the invalid dynamic sql due to the missing expressions.

Comment: Does your user connection have proper grants to the STR_ARR_T object? Also is it possible that it pointing to an synonim instead of the actual object? I've run into alike issue in past.

Comment: Yes I believe so.  Without the synonym and grant execute, I would get oracle exceptions when making the call.  I'm getting into my function but each array element is empty.

Comment: So add some breakpoints to your java code and inspect the myStringArray, maybe you are running into some kind of shadowing variable scope

Comment: My array seems ok.  It's the same array I'm joining for a literal string fix.  But the oracle.sql.ARRAY is suspect.  The elements are in an underlying datumArray of type CHAR, with data fields that appear empty.  Maybe I should look deeper at the api.

Comment: Solved by making my type NVARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR2!

[From the last comment in this post.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708862/couldnt-create-string-oracle-array-of-varchar2-in-jdbc